# word won't print on button press [JS, HTML]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very confused as to why on button press it is not outputting a word. If anyone could help me solve this, that would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried searching for it in other places but I don't know if this is unique problem that only I have (not likely) or if I'm just not good at searching for stuff like this on Google.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Seth's Pictionary Word Generator </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
      function numGen() {
        num = return Math.floor((Math.random() * 43) + 1)
        window.num = nNum;
    }

      var eWords = ["cat", "sun", "cup", "ghost", "flower", "pie", "cow", "banana", "snowflake", "bug", "book", "jar", "snake", "light", "tree", "lips", "apple", "slide", "socks", "smile", "swing", "coat", "shoe", "water", "heart", "hat", "ocean", "kite", "dog", "mouth", "milk", "duck", "eyes", "skateboard", "bird", "boy", "apple", "person", "girl", "mouse", "ball", "house", "star", "nose", "bed", "whale", "jacket", "shirt", "hippo", "beach", "egg", "face", "cookie", "cheese", "ice cream code", "drum", "circle", "spoon", "worm", "spider web"];



      function write() {
        var word = eWords[nNum]
        document.getElementById("wordPlace").innerHTML = word;
  }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 align="center" class="head">SETH'S PICTIONARY GENERATOR</h1>

    <p align="center" class=b> Home of the <strong> best </strong> pictionary generator on the web.</p>

    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;


    <div id="wordPlace">

    </div>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <p align="center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="numGen() write()">
        Generate a word!
      </button>
    </p>

    <footer class=footer>

      <div align="center" class=foot-div>
        Created by gp_swade -- github.com/swodobaggins/pictionary-generator
      </div>

    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: your variables dont match. you've got one called num then you try to refer to it as mNum or something like that.. go over your code carefully and make sure your var names are consistent.

Comment: this: `window.num = nNum;` should be this: `window.nNum = num;`

Comment: `num` is already a global variable in `numGen` because you're not using `var` in front of it, so you now have `window.num` and `window.nNum`... And the `onclick` handler needs a semicolon between the two function calls.

Comment: To avoid issues like this in the future, I'd recommend installing a linter in your text editor (eslint and jshint are good ones for JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My modified, working code: (for some reason jsfiddle and similar sites do not work, but on localhost it works perfectly)

Update: Working on jsfiddle (just change JS "Load type" to "No wrap - in < head>" ):
https://jsfiddle.net/gy2ofu26/

```
...
...
<script>
    var nNum;

    function numGen() {
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 43) + 1);
        nNum = num;
    }

    var eWords = ["cat", "sun", "cup", "ghost", "flower", "pie", "cow", "banana", "snowflake", "bug", "book", "jar", "snake", "light", "tree", "lips", "apple", "slide", "socks", "smile", "swing", "coat", "shoe", "water", "heart", "hat", "ocean", "kite", "dog", "mouth", "milk", "duck", "eyes", "skateboard", "bird", "boy", "apple", "person", "girl", "mouse", "ball", "house", "star", "nose", "bed", "whale", "jacket", "shirt", "hippo", "beach", "egg", "face", "cookie", "cheese", "ice cream code", "drum", "circle", "spoon", "worm", "spider web"];

    function write(){
        var word = eWords[nNum];
        document.getElementById("wordPlace").innerHTML = word;
    }

    function callFunc(){ numGen(); write(); }
</script>
...
...
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="callFunc();">
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Appreciate it a lot.